# Firefox rendering issue when box-shadow and rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

When applying `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);` to a `div` element on Firefox some thin black outline appears around the div.

[image]

The same code renders differently on Chrome as no black outline appears around the div.

I would like to know if this is a FF specific known bug issue and a work around (as after some search I could not find any information).

Notes:
The desired result is a box with no artifacts at the edge like in Chrome.

```html
<div style="position: inherit; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: inherit; height: inherit; transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(0px); backface-visibility: visible; border-radius: 10px; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 1; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); overflow: hidden; display: flex;">
  <div style="width: inherit; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); letter-spacing: 0em; line-height: 1.2em; padding: 16px; overflow-wrap: break-word; text-align: left; align-self: flex-start;">
    <p>Border artifact are rendered in corners only on Firefox.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds <s>normal</s> comprehensible to me :

You are asking to create an box-shadow which starts with 0 offset, 0 blur, 0 spread.

But FF will still try to generate it (just like if it were `1px 1px 0px 0px`).

```css
div{
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px red;
  height: 25px;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Since the border is rounded, the shadow has to be antialiased.

What you see are the antialiasing artifacts.

To avoid it, you can either

- don't set the box-shadow
- set its `color` to transparent
- set it's `spread` to `-1`

```css
div{
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px red;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  }
.no-box{
  box-shadow: none;
  }
.transp{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px transparent;
  }
.minus{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px -1px red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="fail"></div>
<div class="no-box"></div>
<div class="transp"></div>
<div class="minus"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have an idea why FF try to render it as`1px 1px 1px 0px`. Is it a bug in FF?

Comment: @GibboK No it doesn't. My point was that i has to render `1px 1px 0px 0px` (I had a typo btw) or even `0.1px 0px 0px 0px`. So for it, it makes no difference if it's at x 0 y 0 or something else : it has to render it. While doing so, the antialiasing will kick in, leaving those artifacts we see. We could argue that they could be smarter and avoid rendering this exact value, but I'm pretty confident that nothing tells they shouldn't, hence not sure if we can call it a *bug* per se. (But might be worth an bug report anyway if you fell like so).

Answer (score 0):

FF reads `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);` just like
`box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);`

Just simply change the `box-shadow` to `box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);` and you will be okay.

```css
div.styles {
  position: inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) translateZ(0px);
  backface-visibility: visible;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

div.container {
  width: inherit;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding: 16px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="styles">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Border artifact are rendered in corners only on Firefox.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90q9tru1/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not the result I expect. The desired result is no outline at all.

Comment: If you dont want an outline, change the `rbga(0,0,0,1)` to `rgba(0,0,0,0)`

https://jsfiddle.net/90q9tru1/2/ **OR** just delete the box shadow